# 英語が残っている：通報の却下理由

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

モデレーターが通報を却下(decline)するときのメッセージテンプレートが英語のままになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

モデレーターツールのUIが英語なのはいいとしても、この文章は通報したユーザーから見える文章なので、日本語になっていたほうがよいと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

原文

> - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer
> - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
> - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires theire intervention

翻訳案

> - 技術的な問題や間違った回答を指摘するのに通報を使うべきではありません
> - 通報内容を確認しましたが、あなたの主張を支持する証拠が見つかりません
> - 通報機能はモデレーターの介入が必要な投稿を知らせるときにのみお使いください

Comment: これは多言語のサイトにもありますので、現在原因を確認中です（ご存知の通り、Transifex上では当ストリングはありません）

Answer (score 1):

現在使っている翻訳ツールのTraducirによると、以下の通りサイトに反映されております。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/7072
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/2928
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/6248

> - 通報は技術的な不正確さや間違った回答を報告する機能ではありません
> - モデレーターはあなたの通報を確認しましたが、十分な証拠が見つかりませんでした
> - 通報はモデレーターの介入が必要な事象を報告するために使われるべきですが、本件はそうではありません